# Lightning-Input-Field picklist show incorrect value if Record Id changes LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, picklist

I have an LWC ("Child_Component") that displays a lightning-record-edit-form which includes a lightning-input-field that references a picklist. Child_Component receives the record id for the record-edit-form its parent ("Parent_Component"), which has a list of records to choose from.

If I select record A in Parent_Component as the first record after the page loads, the picklist value in Child_Component displays as such:

[image]

This is the result that I want, as it reflects the record's field value.

If I select record B in Parent_Component as the first record after the page loads, the picklist value in Child_Component displays this:

[image]

This also accurately reflects the record's value.

However, if I select record B in Parent_Component first, then change the selected record to record A (without doing a web-page refresh in-between), the picklist value for record A is as follows:

[image]

Other fields are updated as expected. I've confirmed that both the record Id and record type Id are being populated correctly from Parent_Component.

Does anyone know what might be causing this picklist value to fail to update?

**Child_Component**
(The code listed is significantly truncated, additional code can be provided on request)

HTML

```
<lightning-record-edit-form record-id={recordId} record-type-id={recordTypeId} object-api-name="Object_API_Name__c">
    <lightning-input-field variant="label-stacked" field-name="Approval_Response__c"></lightning-input-field>
</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from "lwc";

export default class Child_Component extends LightningElement {
  @api recordId;
  @api recordTypeId;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seemed to have fixed the issue. I added the following code to the JS of Child_Component and the picklist value is updating correctly.

```
 renderedCallback(){
    this.handleLightningInputFieldReset();
  }

  handleLightningInputFieldReset() {
    const inputFields = this.template.querySelectorAll(
        'lightning-input-field'
    );
    if (inputFields) {
        inputFields.forEach(field => {
            field.reset();
        });
    }
 }
```